# Ajax image upload where image gets datetimestamp added to FILENAME and image title get's inserted through MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, upload

Is there any AJAX PHP Jquery MySQL plugin that you can upload multiple files (preferably drag-drop), that add's datetimestamp to the actual FILENAME (where it stores in a folder on the server). Also where you can choose a tile and description that inserts into a MySQL database (the mysql row is going to have the columns as follows: USER_ID,IMAGE_FILENAME,TITLE,DESCRIPTION). I am attempting to make a database for the pictures for my users of my user-based website.

http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/

I've tried modding this properly, just couldn't get it to work...I like the design, functions aren't quite there. Any ideas or suggestions that meet my question?

---

```
<h1>Source Javascript</h1>

function sendFileToServer(formData,status)
{
    var uploadURL ="<? echo $dyn_www; ?>/php_parsers/upload.php"; //Upload URL
    var extraData ={}; //Extra Data.
    var jqXHR=$.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
            var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhrobj.upload) {
                    xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                        var percent = 0;
                        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                        var total = event.total;
                        if (event.lengthComputable) {
                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                        }
                        //Set progress
                        status.setProgress(percent);
                    }, false);
                }
            return xhrobj;
        },
    url: uploadURL,
    type: "POST",
    contentType:false,
    processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            status.setProgress(100);

            $("#status1").append("");         
        }
    }); 

    status.setAbort(jqXHR);
}
var rowCount=0;
function createStatusbar(obj)
{
     rowCount++;
     var row="odd";
     var filename = this.filename;
     if(rowCount %2 ==0) row ="even";

     this.statusbar = $("<div class='statusbar "+row+"'></div>");
     this.filename = $("<div class='filename'></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     this.size = $("<div class='filesize'></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     this.progressBar = $("<div class='progressBar'><div></div></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     this.abort = $("<div class='abort'>Abort</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     this.success = $("<i style=\"color:#009900;display:none\" class=\"fa fa-check-circle\"></i>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     this.titleOfImage = $("<div class='title'><input name='image_file_name' value='"+file_date+"' /><button id=\"title_button_"+row+"\" type=\"submit\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i></div></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
     obj.after(this.statusbar);

    this.setFileNameSize = function(name,size)
    {
        var sizeStr="";
        var sizeKB = size/1024;
        if(parseInt(sizeKB) > 1024)
        {
            var sizeMB = sizeKB/1024;
            sizeStr = sizeMB.toFixed(2)+" MB";
        }
        else
        {
            sizeStr = sizeKB.toFixed(2)+" KB";
        }

        this.filename.html(name);
        this.size.html(sizeStr);
    }
    this.setProgress = function(progress)
    {       
        var progressBarWidth =progress*this.progressBar.width()/ 100;  
        this.progressBar.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 10).html(progress + "% ");
        if(parseInt(progress) >= 100)
        {
            this.abort.hide();
            this.success.show();
            this.titleOfImage.show();
        }
    }
    this.setAbort = function(jqxhr)
    {
        var sb = this.statusbar;
        this.abort.click(function()
        {
            jqxhr.abort();
            sb.hide();
        });
    }
}
function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
{
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{


var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var fulldatetime = ""+ curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year +"";



var filename = files[i].name;
var ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
var allowed= "";
if(ext == "jpg" || ext == "png" || ext == "gif" || ext == "jpeg")
{
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', files[i]);
var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
status.setFileNameSize(files[i].name,files[i].size);
sendFileToServer(fd,status);
}else
{
alert("You are only allowed to upload .jpg, .png, & .gif");
}
} //end for
}


$(document).ready(function()
{
var obj = $("#dragandrophandler");
obj.on('dragenter', function (e) 
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
});
obj.on('dragover', function (e) 
{
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
});
obj.on('drop', function (e) 
{

     $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
     e.preventDefault();
     var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
     //We need to send dropped files to Server
     handleFileUpload(files,obj);
});
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) 
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('dragover', function (e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  obj.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
});
$(document).on('drop', function (e) 
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you need a plugin for this? This is customization, check out [this](http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/) from the same website, it has the PHP code too, you need to get the current date and time and append it to the file name.

Comment: So, using the JavaScript i added in my edit (that came from the website in the link), how could i accomplish my goals with this code.

Comment: You are just copy pasting from the website and not trying to understand what's happening in the code. The link I pasted to you is a simpler version, have a look at it and also read it's documentation [here](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)

Comment: I have completely tried to go through every line of this code. I'm just trying to understand how to append to the filenames...and everything else. I know where the source code is for the upload forms so i i'm not sure why you gave me a more simple link, they still do not accomplish what i am trying to do.

Comment: Could you gave a sample format of how the filename should look like after appending the date and time?

Comment: For example if i upload a image called bg.png, it would turn into 16-03-2014--01-29-55_bg.png (because that is the current datetime)..but i want to pass that through javascript, and not through php (i know how to do that through php) but i need to do it through javascript so i can get the filename after it has been appeneded so i can pack that into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with your code, try:

Replace this block:

```
/*
var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var fulldatetime = ""+ curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year +"";
*/
```

With:

```
 var d = new Date();
    var fulldatetime = d.getDate() + "-"
    + (d.getMonth()+1)  + "-" 
    + d.getFullYear() + "--"  
    + d.getHours() + "-"  
    + d.getMinutes() + "-" 
    + d.getSeconds();
```

And then:

```
var filename = files[i].name;
var ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
/* this line added */
var file_date = fulldatetime+'_'+filename; 
var allowed= "";
if(ext == "jpg" || ext == "png" || ext == "gif" || ext == "jpeg")
{
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', files[i]);
/* this line added */
fd.append('fileDateTime',file_date);
var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
```

The rest of your code remains the same. You can address the new file name with `$_POST['fileDateTime'];` on your `upload.php`

## Addition:

To pass the renamed file to `createStatusbar()`, change the function definition:

from:

```
/* function createStatusbar(obj) */
```

to:

```
function createStatusbar(obj,file_date)
```

and during it's call:

```
/* var status = new createStatusbar(obj);  //Using this we can set progress.*/
```

to:

```
var status = new createStatusbar(obj,file_date); //Using this we can set progress.
```

`file_date` is the variable that holds the new file name, you can then use it as you need.

Comment: This worked perfectly for uploading the files to the server with the timestamp, so thank you very much for that! One last question, is it possbile to be able to access the variable inside of the FormData....i need to be able to echo it earlier in my code (when the file is done uploading [inside of the `createStatusbar`] function on the `this.titleOfImage` line i am trying to echo the variable **file_date**. Is that at anyway possible, becuase it is earlier in the code?

Comment: @AlexSarnowski Yes, that's absolutely possible, please check the edit above.

Comment: Finally, the solution to my seemingly endless problem. Thank you!