# Insert fields into mysql using ajax, multiple and varying amount of instances

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

[Ajax image upload where image gets datetimestamp added to FILENAME and image title get's inserted through MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433129/ajax-image-upload-where-image-gets-datetimestamp-added-to-filename-and-image-tit/22433970?noredirect=1#comment34116584_22433970)

My previous question above, pertaining to an upload form using jquery and php, i asked how to get the timestamp added to the filename and how to load the variable in a previous function on the page, which was solved fairly quickly. Now, my last issue is inserting the form data to my mysql table "user_images"(the form data being the title and description of the image[s]). I have the php code figured out, i just need a code that works dynamically for each image that is uploaded that posts the variables to upload_image_insert.php.

upload_image_insert.php

```
<?php
        include_once(''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php_includes/check_login_status.php');
        $picture_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['picture_title']);
        $picture_filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['picture_filename']);
        $picture_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['picture_description']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users_images (title, filename, description, user_assoc)       
                VALUES('$picture_title','$picture_filename','$picture_description','$log_id')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 

?>
```

Below is the code that executes for each image after they have been successfully uploaded. Now i need to be able to create a javascript code that no matter how many images i upload (the variable being "rowCount"), i can enter the title and description into the inputs and it will post to my **upload_image_insert.php** file.

Javascript Line:

```
this.titleOfImage = $("<div class='title'><form id='myForm_"+rowCount+"' action='<? echo $dyn_www; ?>/php_parsers/upload_image_insert.php' method='post'>Title: <input type='text' name='picture_title' value='' /><input type='hidden' value='"+file_date+"' name='picture_filename' /> <b> | </b> Description : <input type='text' name='picture_description' value='' /><input id='submitbutton' type='submit' name='senddata' value='Submit Data' method='post'><button id='sub_"+row+"'><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i></button></form></div></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
```

Comment: your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: yes, i am aware, i plan on sanitizing variables.